# My python function won't return or update the value

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

```
def getMove(win,playerX,playerY):

    #Define variables.
    movePos = 75
    moveNeg = -75
    running = 1

    #Run while loop constantly to update mouse's coordinates.
    while(running):

        mouseCoord = win.getMouse()
        mouseX = mouseCoord.getX()
        mouseY = mouseCoord.getY()
        print "Mouse X = ", mouseX
        print "Mouse Y = ", mouseY

        if mouseX >= playerX:
            playerX = movePos + playerX
            running = 0
        elif mouseX <= playerX:
            playerX = moveNeg + playerX           
            running = 0
        elif mouseY >= playerY:
            playerY = movePos + playerY            
            running = 0
        elif mouseY <= playerY:
            playerY = moveNeg + playerY            
            running = 0
    return playerX,playerY

def main():

    #Create game window.
    win = GraphWin("Python Game", 500, 500)
    drawBoard(win)

    #Define variables.
    playerX = 75
    playerY = 125
    keyX = 325
    keyY = 375
    running = 1


    #Create Key and Player objects, draw the key, but don't draw the player yet.
    key = Text(Point(keyX,keyY),"KEY")
    key.draw(win)

    while(running):
        print "player X = ", playerX
        print "Player Y = ", playerY
        drawBoard(win)
        getMove(win,playerX,playerY)
        player = Circle(Point(playerX,playerY),22)
        player.setFill('yellow')
        player.draw(win)
main()
```

I am using a graphics library to create a game. My player and key are drawn in the correct places. However, when calling the getMove function, my playerX and playerY do not update. I have added debug print statements to find their values while running the game and it is always 75 and 125. Help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In python, integers are immutable - when you assign a new integer value to a variable, you are just making the variable point to a new integer, not changing what the old integer it pointed to's value was.

(An example of a mutable object in python is the list, which you can modify and all variables pointing to that list will notice the change - since the LIST has changed.)

Similarly, when you pass a variable into a method in python and then alter what the variable points to in that method, you do not alter what the variable points to outside of that method because it is a new variable.

To fix this, assigned the returned playerX,playerY to your variables outside the method:

`playerX, playerY = getMove(win,playerX,playerY)`

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly reassign these variables when you call getMove():

```
playerX, playerY = getMove(win, playerX, playerY)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, the solution is that you're not using the returned values to update your `playerX, playerY` which can be fixed with the mentioned

```
playerX, playerY = getMove(win,playerX,playerY)
```

What I want to address is the logic in your `if` statements. The way you've constructed your `if` statements will lead to only an X OR Y being updated, not both. For example, if `mouseX, mouseY` were both greater than `playerX, playerY` repectively, you'd get to the first line of your `if` statement and it would be evaluated as `True` and update `playerX` accordingly, BUT because the first statement has been executed, none of the other `elif` statements will execute, leading to you only updating the `playerX` variable.

What you want to do is split the `if` statement into two separate statements (one for X and one for Y) so that the adjustments of X,Y are independent of each other. Something similar to

```
    if mouseX >= playerX:
        playerX = movePos + playerX
        running = 0
    elif mouseX <= playerX:
        playerX = moveNeg + playerX           
        running = 0

    #By having the second if, it allows you to check Y even if X has changed
    if mouseY >= playerY:
        playerY = movePos + playerY            
        running = 0
    elif mouseY <= playerY:
        playerY = moveNeg + playerY            
        running = 0
```